# mySql select unique number for every 3 records

Tags: mysql, modulo

I'm trying to get a unique number in 'row' column for every {variable} 3 records. (So I know we have these 3 skus on the first row etc.)

Like this:

```
line    sku   row 
1       aaa   1
2       abb   1
3       abc   1 
4       acc   2
5       acb   2
6       aab   2
7       acc   3
8       acb   3
9       aab   3
```

So what I have is the following

```
SET @rank=0;
SET @rows=3;

 select @rank:=@rank+1 AS line, sku, mod( @rank+1, @rows) 'row'
```

But column 'row' is not as expected.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here give this a go. If i have understood you problem correctly.

```
SET @rank = 0;
SET @rows = 3;
SET @count = 0;

select @rank:=@rank+1 AS line, sku, IF(mod(@rank+1,@rows)=2, @count:=@count+1, @count) AS 'row'
```

Comment: Worked well! Kudos